# php run function on all images from one dir in recursive mode

Tags: php, directory, watermark, recursion

I have a function

```
 $result = create_watermark( 'input_file_name' ,'output_file_name');
```

I have directory called `/images` with 500 images in it. The files are all named `images_(some_unknown_numbers).png` (all png). Now I want run them through a function in a loop and want to output `/markedimage/images_1.png`, `images_2.png`, `images_3.png` and so on.

I want to run this script on Ubuntu so we can use shell too

How can I do this?

Comment: read my reply here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698582/php-run-function-on-all-images-from-one-dir-in-recursive-mode-noob/2698887#2698887

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

foreach (glob("*.png") as $filename) {
    create_watermark($filename, '/watermarked_dir/' . $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want to re-index the numbers for the output files. This example should preserve them:

```
<?php
$dir = './sourceDir';
$outputDir = './markedimage';

//get files matching pattern. maybe you could use glob() instead
$files = scandir($dir);
$files = preg_grep('~^images_\d+.png$~i', $files);

//process each file
foreach ($files as $file) {
     create_watermark( $dir . '/' . $file, $outputDir . '/' . $file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but this should work, too:

```
// Iterate over all filesystem objects in /images
foreach( new DirectoryIterator('/images') as $file ) {
    // check if item is a readable file
    if( $file->isFile() && $file->isReadable() ) {
        // give debug message so we know what the script is doing
        echo "Watermarking $file \n";
        // call your function
        create_watermark(
            // argument 1 is the full path to the image
            $file->getPathname(),
            // argument 2 is the destination folder plus the filename w/out path
            '/markedimage/' . $file->getFilename()
        );
    // tell us if it is not a readable file
    } else {
        echo "Skipped $file \n";
    }
}
```

If there is files in the folder that are not png files, you can use the [GlobIterator](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php) instead of the DirectoryIterator, but that would require PHP5.3.

See

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

i used 2nd answer

working one

```
<?php

foreach (glob("*.png") as $filename) {
    create_watermark($filename, '/watermarked_dir/' . $filename);
}
?>
```

this answer worked without any change  :D thankx but  i can't  vote for it because i m not registered

@1 i m failed to make it working but this i think if put some effort on it it shud work

```
<?php
$dir = './sourceDir';
$outputDir = './markedimage';

//get files matching pattern. maybe you could use glob() instead
$files = scandir($dir);
$files = preg_grep('~^images_\d+.png$~i', $files);

//process each file
foreach ($files as $file) {
     create_watermark( $dir . '/' . $file, $outputDir . '/' . $file);
}

?>
```

thankx to guyz who tried and helped me allot i was try to do this from last 5 hours but failed  her it solved in five minutes

:D thankxxx

Steve